# Using If Conditionals to Exit For Loops VBA/VB

Tags: vba, autodesk-inventor

I am creating a third party add in for my CAD program that has a sub in it that goes through a drawing and finds all the parts lists (BOMS), if any items in the parts list are shared between the BOM (1 part being used in 2 weldments for example) then it changes the item number of the second instance to be that of the first instance. It does this by comparing full file names between the two values. When they match change the number to that of the matcher. I have got this to work but it runs a little slow because for a 100 item BOM each item is compared to 100 and thus that takes a little longer then I would like (about 60seconds to run). After thinking about it I realized I did not need to compare each item to all the items, I just needed to compare until it found a duplicate and then exit the search loop and go to the next value. Example being Item 1 does not need to compare to the rest of the 99 values because even if it does have a match in position 100 I do not want to change item 1s number to that of item 100. I want to change item 100 to that of 1(ie change the duplpicate to that of the first encountered double). For my code however I am having trouble exiting the comparison for loops which is causing me trouble. An example of the trouble is this:

I have 3 BOMs, each one shares Part X, and is numbered 1 in BOM 1, 4 in BOM 2, and 7 in BOM 3. when I run my button because I cannot get it to leave the comparison loop once it finds it first match all the Part X's ended up getting item number 7 from BOM 3 because it is the last instance. (I can get this to do what I want by stepping through my for loops backwards and thus everything ends up as the top most occurrence, but I would like to get my exit fors working because it saves me on unnecessary comparisons)

How do I go about breaking out of the nested for loops using an if conditional?

Here is my current code:

```
Public Sub MatchingNumberR1()

Debug.Print ThisApplication.Caption

'define active document as drawing doc. Will produce an error if its not a drawing doc
    Dim oDrawDoc As DrawingDocument
    Set oDrawDoc = ThisApplication.ActiveDocument

    'Store all the sheets of drawing
    Dim oSheets As Sheets
    Set oSheets = oDrawDoc.Sheets
    
    Dim oSheet As Sheet
        
        'Loop through all the sheets
        For Each oSheet In oSheets

        Dim oPartsLists As PartsLists
        Set oPartsLists = oSheet.PartsLists
        
        'Loop through all the part lists on that sheet
        Dim oPartList As PartsList
        
            'For every parts list on the sheet
            For Each oPartList In oPartsLists
            
                For i3 = 1 To oPartList.PartsListRows.Count
                
                    'Store the Item number and file referenced in that row to compare
                    oItem = FindItem(oPartList)
                    oDescription = FindDescription(oPartList)
                    oDescripCheck = oPartList.PartsListRows.Item(i3).Item(oDescription).Value
                    oNumCheck = oPartList.PartsListRows.Item(i3).Item(oItem).Value
                    
                    
                    'Check to see if the BOM item is a virtual component if it is do not try and get the reference part
                    If oPartList.PartsListRows.Item(i3).ReferencedFiles.Count = 0 Then
                        oRefPart = " "
                    End If
                    
                    'Check to see if the BOM item is a virtual component if it is try and get the reference part
                    If oPartList.PartsListRows.Item(i3).ReferencedFiles.Count > 0 Then
                        oRefPart = oPartList.PartsListRows.Item(i3).ReferencedFiles.Item(1).FullFileName
                    End If
                    
                    MsgBox (" We are comparing " & oRefPart)
                    
    '''''Create a comparison loop to go through the drawing that checks the oRefPart against other BOM items and see if there is a match.'''''
    
    
    
    'Store all the sheets of drawing
    
                Dim oSheets2 As Sheets
                Set oSheets2 = oDrawDoc.Sheets
                Dim oSheet2 As Sheet
        
        
                    'For every sheet in the drawing
                    For Each oSheet2 In oSheets2

                    'Get all the parts list on a single sheet
                    Dim oPartsLists2 As PartsLists
                    Set oPartsLists2 = oSheet2.PartsLists
                    Dim oPartList2 As PartsList
       
            
                        'For every parts list on the sheet
                        For Each oPartList2 In oPartsLists2
            
                            oItem2 = FindItem(oPartList2)
                            oDescription2 = FindDescription(oPartList2)
                
            
                            'Go through all the rows of the part list
                            For i6 = 1 To oPartList2.PartsListRows.Count
                
                                'Check to see if the part is a not a virtual component, if not, get the relevent comparison values
                                If oPartList2.PartsListRows.Item(i6).ReferencedFiles.Count > 0 Then
                     
                                    oNumCheck2 = oPartList2.PartsListRows.Item(i6).Item(oItem2).Value
                                    oRefPart2 = oPartList2.PartsListRows.Item(i6).ReferencedFiles.Item(1).FullFileName
                            
                                        'Compare the file names, if they match change the part list item number for the original to that of the match
                                        If oRefPart = oRefPart2 Then
                                        oPartList.PartsListRows.Item(i3).Item(1).Value = oNumCheck2
                            
                            
                            ''''''''This is where I want it to exit the loop and grab the next original value'''''''
                                        End If
                    
                   
                                'For virtual components get the following comparison values
                                ElseIf oPartList2.PartsListRows.Item(i6).ReferencedFiles.Count = 0 Then
                                           
                                           
                                    oNumCheck2 = oPartList2.PartsListRows.Item(i6).Item(oItem2).Value
                                    oDescripCheck2 = oPartList2.PartsListRows.Item(i6).Item(oDescription2).Value
                                    'Compare the descriptions and if they match change the part list item number for the original to that of the match
                                        If oDescripCheck = oDescripCheck2 Then
                                        oPartList.PartsListRows.Item(i3).Item(1).Value = oNumCheck2
                            
                            
                            ''''''''This is where I want it to exit the loop and grab the next original value'''''''
                                        End If
                 
                                         
                    
                            Else
                   
                            ''''''''This is where if no matches were found I want it to continue going through the comparison loop'''''''
                            End If
                    
                    
                    Next
                    Next
                    Next
                    
               Next
            Next
       Next
        
    'MsgBox ("Matching Numbers has been finished")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For escape from nested for loop you can use `GoTo` and specify where.

```
Sub GoToTest()
    Dim a, b, c As Integer
    
    For a = 0 To 1000 Step 100
        For b = 0 To 100 Step 10
            For c = 0 To 10
                Debug.Print vbTab & b + c
                If b + c = 12 Then
                    GoTo nextValueForA
                End If
            Next
        Next
nextValueForA:
        Debug.Print a + b + c
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few examples that demonstrate (1) breaking out of (exiting) a loop and (2) finding the values in arrays.

The intersection of 2 arrays example can be modified to meet your need to "Create a comparison loop to go through the drawing that checks the oRefPart against other BOM items and see if there is a match." Note, you may find multiple matches between 2 arrays.

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 0

' Example - break out of loop when condition met.
Public Sub ExitLoopExample()
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    
    ' let's loop 101 times
    For i = 0 To 100:
        j = i * 2
        'Print the current loop number to the Immediate window
        Debug.Print i, j
        ' Let's decide to break out of the loop is some
        ' condition is met.  In this example, we exit
        ' the loop if j>=10.  However, any condition can
        ' be used.
        If j >= 10 Then Exit For
    Next i
End Sub


' Example - break out of inner loop when condition met.
Public Sub ExitLoopExample2()
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

    For i = 1 To 5:
        For j = 1 To 5
            Debug.Print i, j
            ' if j >= 2 then, exit the inner loop.
            If j >= 2 Then Exit For
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub


Public Sub FindItemInArrayExample():
' Find variable n in array arr.
    Dim intToFind As Integer
    Dim arrToSearch As Variant
    Dim x, y
    
    intToFind = 4
    arrToSearch = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

    x = FindItemInArray(FindMe:=intToFind, _
                        ArrayToSearch:=arrToSearch)
    
    If IsEmpty(x) Then
        Debug.Print intToFind; "not found in arrToSearch"
    Else
        Debug.Print "found "; x
    End If
    
    intToFind = 12
    y = FindItemInArray(FindMe:=intToFind, _
                        ArrayToSearch:=arrToSearch)
                        
    If IsEmpty(y) Then
        Debug.Print intToFind; "not found in arrToSearch"
    Else
        Debug.Print "found "; y
    End If
End Sub

Public Function FindItemInArray(FindMe, ArrayToSearch As Variant):
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = LBound(ArrayToSearch) To UBound(ArrayToSearch)
        If FindMe = ArrayToSearch(i) Then
            FindItemInArray = ArrayToSearch(i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

End Function


' Create a comparison loop to go through the drawing that checks
' the oRefPart against other BOM items and see if there is a match.
Public Sub ArrayIntersectionExample():
    Dim exampleArray1 As Variant, exampleArray2 As Variant
    Dim arrIntersect As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    
    ' Create two sample arrays to compare
    exampleArray1 = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
    exampleArray2 = Array(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16)
    
    ' Call our ArrayIntersect function (defined below)
    arrIntersect = ArrayIntersect(exampleArray1, exampleArray2)
    
    ' Print the results to the Immediate window
    For i = LBound(arrIntersect) To UBound(arrIntersect)
        Debug.Print "match " & i + 1, arrIntersect(i)
    Next i
End Sub

Public Function ArrayIntersect(arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant) As Variant:
' Find items that exist in both arr1 and arr2 (intersection).
' Return the intersection as an array (Variant).
    Dim arrOut() As Variant
    Dim matchIndex As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    
    ' no matches yet
    matchIndex = -1
    ' begin looping through arr1
    For i = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
        ' sub-loop for arr2 for each item in arr1
        For j = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
            ' check for match
            If arr1(i) = arr2(j) Then
                ' we found an item in both arrays
                
                ' increment match counter, which we'll
                ' use to size our output array
                matchIndex = matchIndex + 1
                ' resize our output array to fit the
                ' new match
                ReDim Preserve arrOut(matchIndex)
                ' now store the new match our output array
                arrOut(matchIndex) = arr1(i)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    ' Have the function return the output array.
    ArrayIntersect = arrOut
End Function
```